# I am not able to figure out why the value of s is getting changed based on the previous call in recursion?

Tags: python-3.x, string, recursion

```
def palindrome(s):
    if len(s)==1:
        return s
    else:
        reversed=palindrome(s[1:]) +  s[0]
        return reversed

s='lennox'
if s==palindrome(s):
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

In this code after every function call **s** value is getting changed. How  does this happen?

Actually my values of s are :-

'lennox'
'ennox'
'nnox'
'nox'
'ox'

But in function s values are taken as:-

'ox'
'nox'
'nnox'
'ennox'
'lennox'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here: `palindrome(s[1:])`

now in the next `palindrome()`, `s = s[1:]`

**EDIT**:

Recursive is something like a Last in, first out stack.

step 1: palindrome('lennox')

because of this sentence: `reversed=palindrome(s[1:]) +  s[0]`, you have to ge the value of palindrome(s[1:]) first.

so we now have step 2: palindrome('ennox')

...

Now we have the last step 6: `palindrome('x')`, `return s`, it returns `x`

your step 5 stack will recieve the result of `reversed=palindrome(s[1:]) + s[0]`, and returns `ox`

...

finally, step 1 function received the result of (step2, step3, step4, step5, step6), and returns `lennox`.

Too tired to type each step, hope you can understand.

Comment: Yes but why s value going in a reverse direction . I updated the question how s value is getting changed.